# Accessing Ras Pi 3 phpmyadmin on windows machine

Tags: windows, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi3

I've got an Arduino hooked up to a Raspberry Pi 3 via USB and feeding some analog data to a database I created.

I've set up a database on my Raspberry Pi 3 (have everything set up phpMyAdmin and MySQL). I'm feeding data into it and it works. I want to access the database through my Windows machine, though. I have Apache, phpMyAdmin, and MySQL all installed.

I'm pretty sure I've edited/copied all files correctly and I can get to localhost/phpmyadmin on my windows machine.

I'm just not sure what I need to do to get to my Pi's database from there. Working with Wifi currently. I don't necessarily have access to a router since I'm working of my apartment building's wifi. I have VPN installed on Pi but haven't really configured it yet if that's the route I need to take.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since the database exists on your Raspberry Pi, you don't need to have MySQL installed on your Windows machine. You generally only need one MySQL server which can be accessed by many clients. In this case, since you want to use phpMyAdmin to access the data, you have the option of installing phpMyAdmin on your Windows machine or the Raspberry Pi. I highly recommend putting it on the Pi, because it simplifies the connection process to have it on the same machine that MySQL is using.

You'll need some supporting software to get phpMyAdmin running; a web server and the PHP interpreter. These are all easily available on the Raspberry Pi (depending on your operating system, of course; I use Raspbian and there are packages distributed for each). Then you'd use the web browser on your Windows machine to access the web server on the Pi (likely through the IP address; you'll have to query your Pi to figure out what the address is, perhaps with `ip addr` at the command prompt).

You can certainly use phpMyAdmin installed on your Windows machine instead, but then need to ensure that the MySQL daemon is listening for network connections and that you have a user permitted to connect from an external network connection (I'm seeing that many packages are restricting both of these, as a security precaution, in their distributions now). It's easy to enable yourself, but easier to just connect from a local PHP instance.

Unless your machines are on two different networks or you wish to connect to your home network from an outside connection on the Internet, you shouldn't need the VPN for this project. Your wifi is likely supplied by a router that's giving you a local address and will allow you to connect to other machines on your local network segment, so once you find the IP address you should be able to connect directly.